# Syncing bookmarks in Firefox' own "Bookmarks" menu with bookmarks of Android (4.0) phone

Tags: firefox, sync, android, bookmarks

Is it possible to make Firefox sync its own bookmarks (accessible from the "Bookmarks" menu) with the bookmarks on my phone (Galaxy S3 running Android 4.0), so that when I add a bookmark in Firefox on my PC it's there on my phone, and vice versa?

Researching this I thought it would be easy to find an add-on that does this, but I can't find one. I can find:

1. add-ons that create their own bookmarks menu and syncs that to my Google account (which is presumably what I need to access them from my phone)
2. add-ons that seem to sync Firefox' own bookmarks, but not with my Google account

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can.. on Firefox latest browser you can sync between your pc and your device this is the help https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-a-device-to-firefox-sync#w_add-an-android-or-maemo-device